# Extracting values from listbox

Tags: vba, excel

I created a UserForm in VBA with 2 ListBoxes.

[image: Screenshot of UserForm]

What I want to do is extract values from the right ListBox (and keep them in temp) and delete every row in another sheet which contains these names.

Writing a code to delete rows is not an issues. I have no clue how to use these selected items in another VBA module. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you populating that listbox in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can save them in a Collection, and then use that Collection as argument in other Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Update to process rows in reverse (since delete will shift rows up). See comments at top of code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub cmdDelete_Click()
    ' This subroutine will allow a user to delete selected rows from an Excel sheet.
    ' In a multi-select listbox on a user form, select the items that you want to delete.
    ' Click the 'Delete' button on the form and the following will occur:
    ' a. Each selected item will be delimited and concatenated into one string.
    '    (The reason for doing that is to avoid spinning thru each listbox item for
    '    every row)
    ' b. Each row in the selected range will have it's value checked within the string.
    ' c. If found. the row will be deleted.
    '
    ' Notes: - Need to loop thru the rows from bottom upwards to top because
    '          as each row is deleted, it will shift remainder upwards.
    '        - You don't really need the delimiters if values can never be confused

    Dim sList       As String
    Dim lItem       As Long
    Dim r           As Range
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim lFirstRow   As Long
    Dim lLastRow    As Long
    Dim lRow        As Long

    For lItem = 0 To lstCountries.ListCount - 1
        If lstCountries.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            sList = sList & "<" & Me.lstCountries.column(0, lItem) & ">"     ' Adjust to the column YOU want (relative to zero)
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print "Full List to Delete: " & sList

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")      ' Change to YOUR worksheet name
    ' Find the last used row
    lLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lFirstRow = 2                               ' Set to YOUR first used row

    ' Spin thru all rows in the range of rows
    ' Go in reverse order since the Delete will shift the rows UP
    For lRow = lLastRow To lFirstRow Step -1
        ' See if row value exists in the selections made in the listbox
        If InStr(1, sList, "<" & ws.Cells(lRow, 1) & ">") > 0 Then
            ws.Rows(lRow).Delete            ' Delete row if a match is found
        End If
    Next lRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, using your code will not work 100% of the time. Since Excel will shift rows up after the delete, and the 'Next C' will move to the NEXT row, you may miss a row that you want to delete. A simple solution is to get the row count of your range, then do a 'For i = iMaxRow to iStartRow Step -1'

Comment: Actually this code didn't work for me. Nevertheless it inspired me to use double upload. In my answer you will find my approach which works perfectly fine.

Comment: I assume you made the necessary code corrections to specify your own environment? In my test, the listbox has 10+ items and I selected three of them. In Sheet1, column A, I entered test data that would sometimes match and sometimes not. All of the matching rows were deleted. Glad you got your own to work and looking  forward to see what you post as your solution...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would like my code to look more like this:

```
For Each c In Range
    If c.Value = [any of values from list box] Then
        c.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: My answer will spin thru each item you selected in a ListBox. Put whatever code you want for deleting. What do you mean you want your code to look like what you posted? That does not reference the Listbox?

Comment: The case is that I don't know how to reference to ListBox in this fragment "If c.Value = [any of values from list box]"

Comment: How many rows will you normally find in your 'Range'? You will need to nest one piece of code or the other (loop thru ListBox and find rows to delete, or loop thru rows and find if in listbox). One easy way to do this would be to build a delimited string of all selection in listbox, then for each row see if the delimited value is in the string you built. I can show you some code to handle either way...

Comment: So please show me the code. If I understand you correctly I should have 2 nested loops (loop through list and rows or the other way around)

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my issue

```
Private Sub delete_button_Click()

On Error Resume Next

Dim custom_range(1 To 5) As Range

Set custom_range(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Countries").Columns(5).Cells
Set custom_range(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Operations").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Costs").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(4) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Columns(2).Cells

For i = 0 To ListBox_selected_countries.ListCount - 1
    country_to_delete = ListBox_selected_countries.List(i)

    For j = 1 To 5
    Set active_range = custom_range(j)
        For Each c In active_range
            If c.Value = country_to_delete Then
                c.EntireRow.delete
            End If
        Next c
    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```